Doing schoolwork
In the book The report card, it says

the real reason I began being a cat at school was because I knew if I started doing schoolwork in kindergarten, it would be too easy.

What does it mean by doing schoolwork in kindergarten? Do children at kindergarten do schoolwork there? Please explain.

This is a cultural question more than an English question, so I don't think it's a good fit for this site.

That said, yes. American kindergarten (usually for children ages 5-6), involves schoolwork. Most public (state run) schools have kindergarten students learning reading, writing, and arithmetic along with other subjects like science and social studies. Students often spend multiple hours a day sitting at tables or desks and working on worksheets or whiteboards. They practice penmanship, adding and subtracting, phonics, spelling, and grammar. Kindergarten students in the US often have homework which is often worksheets or other practice tasks to complete between school days.

In the US, there are many types of schools, and parents who have the money and access to do so can choose where to send their children. Every school is a little different, so this description is not applicable to every school, but it is an accurate generalization and is what the book is referring to.

What does this have to do with the English language? The words mean what the dictionary says they mean, and the user isn't new or ignorant. It seems to be asking about American educational practices which are off-topic.

Similarly in UK nursery school (our kindergarten equivalent). They help children with basic literacy and mathematical skills. My siblings and I could all read and write before we went to 'proper' school, for which a basis in "the three Rs" is a great help.

What book? Please tell us.

Is it The Report Card by Andrew Clements? If so, then 9-y-o Nora in 5th grade isn't exactly kindergarten, perhaps reminiscing.

I'm guessing you're asking this question because you doubt that American kindergartners are subjected to school work so young, and so you want to know if the phrase "doing schoolwork" has some other meaning.
In fact, American kindergartners commonly do schoolwork in class, and there is no idiosyncratic meaning here to the phrase "doing schoolwork".

I want to appreciate your kind explanation for my question though it was quite absurd and off the purpose of this site. Thank you.
